# Select max from groups in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
NAME,THING,NUM
abc,thing1,9
abc,thing1,1
abc,thing2,3
abc,thing2,1
jkl,thing1,88
jkl,thing1,12
jkl,thing2,13
jkl,thing2,14
xyz,thing1,37
xyz,thing1,3
xyz,thing2,101
xyz,thing2,99
```

How do I query this to find the highest ranking total for the second column for each value in the first column? Such as:

```
abc,thing1,10
jkl,thing1,100
xyz,thing2,200
```

This query:

```sql
SELECT 
    NAME, 
    THING, 
    SUM(NUM) 
FROM this_table 
GROUP BY NAME, THING;
```

yields this result:

```
abc,thing1,10
abc,thing2,4
jkl,thing1,100
jkl,thing2,27
xyz,thing1,40
xyz,thing2,200
```

but I just want the highest value for each name and thing.

Comment: Your example is a SUM, not a MAX. If you want a MAX use, `max()` instead of `sum()` but it is not clear what you want as your question is contradictory and the example desired output does not match the data you provided.

Comment: Having created the sums for the first two columns you'd need to use a windows function to create a rank (row_number)  for each row within the groups you define and then a final WHERE clause to filter where the rank = 1. So probably 2 CTEs and then the final SQL statement

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: @TheImpaler  SQLite and DB2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention the database, so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select name, thing, sum(num) as s,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by sum(num) desc) as rn
  from t
  group by name, thing
) x
where rn = 1
```

See running example at [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nyI1exxO).

Comment: This worked perfectly. I would not have figured this out on my own: I haven't seen `row_number`, `over`, `partition by` before nor do I understand the need for the `x` alias after the window function.